# Can God be angry with their devotees? Help me

Tags: spiritual

well, my spiritual life is very complicated. Since I became a Hindu, it took me a long time to reveal this to my family. Almost two months ago, I made a promise to Narayan that I would reveal my faith to my relatives (who are devout Christians), but in my misfortune, I did not have the courage to do so and I was unable to keep the promise. It's been almost 2 weeks since I finally had the courage and said to my family, they reacted very badly, but unfortunately I knew that this would happen. Almost 2 months after I made the promise, I finally managed to keep it, but here's the problem. Before that promise, I had many spiritual experiences, especially one where I met Lord Shiva in a puja and meditation session directed at Kali Ma, I even consider Kali Ma to be my Ishta Devata, in that particular event, things happened that made me confirm the truth of that faith that I follow. But ever since I broke that promise, I can't concentrate on any spiritual session, and my doubts, which were no longer there, now come back to me to doubt everything.

I know that many people say that Kali Ma, because of her ferocity, does not like to be left behind, so what frightens me the most is that now I can't keep up with anything because She is mad at me. I really need help, what should I do?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44558/22556 this will help you. You can ask for forgiveness.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works. It is more like the product of your imagination and mind. There are many people who do things worse than you but nothing happens to them. You are thinking too much.

Comment: Hare Krishna!
Actually Sri Kalikambal is not like how she is portrayed in movies and serials.
She is the Mother of the universe.
She is kind and will listen to your prayers.
You can pray to her to forgive you.
Don't be scared because fear is our greatest enemy.
Thanks Om Namo Narayanaya!

Comment: Hello! Welcome to HSE. Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer [personalized advice](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/asking-for-help-solutions-to-solve-personal-issues-should-be-considered-off-to), and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor. But anyway to answer you, consider God as your dearest and closest friend who understands you. Don't ask for forgiveness but be humble and loyal with him/her.

Comment: God does not become angry. God is perfect. If He became angry it would mean He was imperfect. Do you become angry when you see two ants fighting? Or 2 puppies angry at each other? To become angry is a sign of imperfection. Angry arises from want and desire. See Gita 2.62-63